# What is the first tier of raids in Mist of Pandaria?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Watching [the stream of the guild that Arqade sponsers](http://www.twitch.tv/team/midwinter) got me wondering what raids are available in the first tier of raiding(the tier being tested in Mist of Pandaria Beta) and who is the main antagonist in each raid?

Comment: Any answer to question this question would be pure speculation. If you think back to before Firelands, we were expecting a Vashj'ir raid, but it never happened.

Comment: @Koviko since raid testing has started we can be pretty sure that the number of raids and main antagonist is pretty much set, but I will give you that they might changed the number of bosses each will have.

Comment: @koviko the raids are in testing, *right now.* there's nothing speculative about it.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz It's plenty speculative. Beta is beta. Unless any of our members are Blizzard representatives, we can't guarantee that all of those raids will make it to release, nor can we guarantee that those will be the only raids or that they won't be altered or replaced.

Comment: @Koviko it is close enough to release to have [a promotion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5197/mists-of-pandaria-beta-play-ask-answer-win) about it, so I think it is also close enough to ask questions about it.

Comment: @Blem On that note, why not just ask what raids are currently in the Beta?

Comment: @Koviko modified question to reflect it

Comment: Mogu'shan Vaults is on the beta for testing.  It's highly unlikely that anything will change there, at least not relating to the names and roles of the bosses.  The others all have dungeon journals written for them, and it's hard to act like they won't be a part of the actual release.  That's not to say that they might completely overhaul a fight or add in new ones.

Comment: Withdrawing my "too localized" opinion.  There is now an official quotable from blizzard for the original question.  http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6201711873?page=4#77

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Blizzard, the initial raid content is [going to be split up into three mini-tiers](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5058396227?page=1#1), with Mogu'shan Vaults being the first of these tiers:

#### 1. Mogu'shan Vaults

Open one week after launch for normal raiders, the main adversary is the Will of the Emperor, which is less of a boss than an event, [as described by Ion Hazzikostas](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/blog/5395467/World_of_Warcraft_Mists_of_Pandaria_Raid_Preview-31_07_2012), lead encounter designer:

> The core chamber of the Vaults contains an army of terracotta warriors that are built into recesses within the walls. If players look up, they’ll see these statue-filled niches stretching above them into the distance. When the players enter, the statues begin animating and attacking in huge waves, and the fight quickly turns into a free-for-all. There will be certain heavy-hitting statues that require tanking, and many of the other statues have special abilities to keep the non-tanks busy. It’s going to be a crazy fight that requires lots of crowd control.

The next two mini-tiers are reportedly the Heart of Fear and the Terrace of Endless Spring, which correspond to two parts of the same narrative:

#### 2. Heart of Fear

Open four weeks after Mogu'shan Vaults for normal raiders, the main adversary is Grand Empress Shek'zeer, who:

> has been possessed by the Sha of Fear

#### 3. Terrace of Endless Spring

Open for normal raiders once they complete the Heart of Fear, the main adversary is the Sha of Fear, who:

> has escaped the Heart of Fear once Grand Empress Shek'zeer was defeated.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: Didn't see that the answer above also has the dates (not with numbers but with words) sorry for the repetition)**

Adding this answer to add the exact dates of the releases of these raids (as they are not accessible right from the start):

> September 25: MoP launches
>
> October 2: Mogu'shan Vaults (normal) opens
>
> October 7: Mogu'shan Vaults (LFR) opens, those who cleared normal Vaults can access heroic mode
>
> October 30: Heart of Fear and Terrace of Endless Spring (normal) open, with Terrace only accessible by clearing Heart
>
> November 6: Heart of Fear and Terrace of Endless Spring (LFR) open; queuing for Terrace requires clearing Heart. Those who cleared normal Heart can access heroic Heart, same for Terrace.

Source: http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6201711873?page=13#259

Answer (score 2):

There are currently three raids that have been announced: Heart of Fear, Mogu'shan Vaults, and Terrace of Endless Spring.  Currently, only Mogu'shan Vaults has been unveiled and opened for testing on the beta.  The other two are highly subject to change before we know more.  The Vaults will most likely be released similar to how they are on the beta.

Blizzard [announced](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6201711873?page=4#77) that the three raids will be released in stages, with Heart of Fear opening up four weeks after Mogu'shan Vaults, and Terrace of Endless Spring opened once players clear the Heart of Fear.

These descriptions are available on the beta in the dungeon journals.  If you don't have access to the beta, they are also referenced and kept updated at [wowpedia](http://www.wowpedia.org/Dungeon_Journal_Mists_of_Pandaria_raids).

### Mogu'shan Vaults

Description: The [mogu](http://www.wowpedia.org/Mogu), proud of their supremacy, kept lengthy records of their accomplishments within a great complex of vaults. Guarded by ferocious magical beings, these sacred chambers have remained silent since the mogu's departure.

**Bosses**

The Stone Guard - The first line of defense against those daring to enter the vaults is a stolid row of enchanted, bestial statues. Hard as granite and ceaseless in their vigil, the sentries of the Stone Guard present an insurmountable wall of flame, fangs, and claws.

Feng the Accursed - Long ago, Feng Shri was the Mogu'shan Vaults' caretaker, tasked with preserving the treasures kept within these shadowy halls. After years of faithful service, he was caught stealing from the shelves, although some say he was framed by a jealous underling and the mogu ruler punished him with a fatal curse. The doomed spirit of Feng Shri has wandered the vaults ever since, communing with the shades of past mogu heroes and warlords.

Gara'jal the Spiritbinder - Leader of the Zandalar trolls' assault on the vaults, Gara'jal is determined to crack open this trove of ancient mystery and bring back whatever arcane power and knowledge he can find. Gifted with dark talents and surrounded by a loyal cadre of Zandalar mystics, he has broken through the outer walls and will not rest until the vaults belong to him.

The Spirit Kings - Ancient records tell of these legendary rulers, powerful mogu who carved an empire out of the very rock of Pandaria. Their names still cause the lands to tremble: Zian of the Endless Shadow, Meng Sharpfang, Qiang Steelskin, and Sebotai Swiftfoot. Some say their spirits lurk in the vaults, lost in ghostly memories of battle and glory.

Elegon - Dedicated to the advancement of their empire, the mogu salvaged and repurposed titan technology to generate untold power in the depths of this ancient complex. Why these energies have been focused into the cold will of a celestial dragon is a mystery that lies at the very heart of the vaults.

Will of the Emperor - The core chamber of the vaults is protected by stone soldiers who have been motionless for centuries. They are row upon row of warriors, statues armed for a battle that never began. What treasures do they guard? And what is their tie to the titanic power buried with them here in the shadows?

### Heart of Fear

Description: This is the seat of the Mantid dominion, and a place where the Queen of the Mantid currently resides, possessed by the Sha of Fear.  It is located in a large, rotting tree structure in the center of the Dread Wastes.

**Bosses**

Imperial Vizier Zor'lok - Zor'lok shrieks his proclamations so they're heard throughout the sprawling mantid palace. He is the Voice of the Empress, and his words alone inspire the insectoid race's warriors to give their lives without question. Unwaveringly loyal, Zor'lok will stop at nothing to defend his beloved matriarch, regardless of the corruption within her.

Blade Lord Ta'yak - Ta'yak is known for his patience and intelligence. In battle, he is a master at discovering his opponent's weaknesses and awaiting the perfect opportunity to strike. Ta'yak's skill with a blade is unmatched, and he cherishes imparting his martial knowledge on young mantid warriors.

Wind Lord Mel'jarak - Wind Lord Mel'jarak commands the mantid's numerous aerial forces. Although he exudes arrogance, the cunning insectoid is fiercely protective of his soldiers and enjoys fighting at their side. Mel'jarak believes the mantid are superior to all other races, convinced that his kind cannot be defeated.

Garalon - It may be time to reconsider stepping on bugs. Don't make fun of this hulking behemoth's tiny wings; that'll just make him angry (Garalon is a massive [Kunchong](http://www.wowpedia.org/Kunchong)).

Amber-Shaper Unsok - Eager to please his empress, Un'sok has produced several innovative concoctions. Yet this brilliant young alchemist's proximity to the mantid queen has allowed the sha's negative energies to take root in his mind. Now, Un'sok's overwhelming fear of failure drives him to create increasingly deadlier weapons.

Grand Empress Shek'zeer - The ancient Klaxxi order has come to a mournful decision: the tainted grand empress Shek'zeer must be deposed. Traditionally, mantid rulers are displaced in their old age by a carefully chosen successor. However, Shek'zeer's intended replacement is still too young and weak to unseat her, leaving the Klaxxi with no choice but to kill the current empress. If action is not taken against her soon, all of Pandaria may crumble before the mantid's ravenous swarms.

### Terrace of Endless Spring

Description: Straddling the mountain range between the Jade Forest and the Vale of Eternal Blossoms, the Terrace of Endless Spring has been a sacred refuge for millennia. Its peaceful fountains are said to have the power to heal and rejuvenate, but when the Sha of Fear attacked, many of the complex's guardians turned on each other in fits of terror.

Before a player can attempt to enter Terrace of Endless Spring, the Heart of Fear raid must be completed first. This will be a short four-boss raid.

**Bosses**

Protectors of the Endless - When the Sha of Fear invaded the Terrace of Endless Spring, three venerated jinyu protectors were corrupted, and they betrayed the other mortal sentinels, slaying them all. The twisted guardians have now turned their attention to any intruders who might interrupt the sha's attack on the area's last defenses.

Tsulong - Legends speak of a spiraling, golden serpent that can sometimes be seen high in the sky, basking in the sunlight above the clouds. The few who claim to have observed it themselves say the creature is fiercely protective of the terrace.

Lei Shi - For countless years, this friendly water spirit frolicked in the Fountains of Endless Spring with childlike wonder and glee. When fighting suddenly broke out in this peaceful place, Lei Shi saw the crystal-clear water turn cloudy and murky, and terror fell over her mind.

Sha of Fear - The Sha of Fear is the physical manifestation of terror in Pandaria. Imprisoned by the legendary pandaren emperor Shaohao long ago, the entity has been newly strengthened by rising conflict across the island.  It should be noted that this entity is personally responsible for the corruption of the mantid swarm through Grand Empress Shek'zeer.

Comment: This reads like sales copy: did you write this yourself, or did you copy it from somewhere?

Comment: Looks like this was taken wholesale from http://www.wowhead.com/news=204817/mists-of-pandaria-loot-tables-and-dungeon-journals.  In cases like this you're expected to link the source; plagiarizing is extremely frowned upon.

Comment: I actually never saw that page.  Almost all of this info is taken from the dungeon journals, which is available on the beta.  Do we really have to link to the source when the source is the game?

Comment: @Ben You need to add attribution to anything you didn't personally write, regardless of where it came from.