# Do I need to finish Mogu'shan Vaults in order to do Heart of Fear?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have read that one must complete the Heart of Fear raid in order to participate in the Terrace of Endless Spring raid. In order to participate in the Heart of Fear raid, does one need to complete the Mogu'shan Vaults raid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [you just need to wait for the raid to unlock on October 30th, 2012](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/7435940/Mogu%E2%80%99shan_Vaults_Now_Live__Raid_Schedule-10_2_2012). The only attunement required is the one you mentioned: Heart of Fear must be completed in order to enter the Terrace of Endless Spring, due to [the nature of the lore surrounding the raids](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/79311/3389).

Comment: [High-rated Wowhead comments](http://www.wowhead.com/zone=6297/heart-of-fear#comments:id=1701008) can be misleading, sometimes. This is why I decided to ask here. :)

Comment: @Koviko right, that comment is incorrect; Blizzard never said anything of the sort. MoP raiding is not indented to be a throwback to BC; the only reason Terrace requires HoF is because its plot is a direct sequel to the plot of HoF.